# How to make borders equally bold boostrap 3.3.7 class="table table-bordered"

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7 and I'm experiencing an issue of some borders between cells to be bolder
than others

[image]

I'm not sure if I'm going crazy or some borders are really bolder than others. How to make borders look equally bold?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm experiencing same problem too

Comment: It seems to be not possible as it is related to a screen resolution (at least in my situation) if you reset your screen to 100% everything should be fine.